# Dynamic Height of Webview according to content with scrolling disabled

Tags: c#, html, webview, windows-phone-8.1

I need to show html content like a textblock in Store App 8.1. I have created a webview and navigate this webview to the html string coming dynamically. After this I call a script to disable the scrolling in WebView but I am not able to set the height of WebView according to the amount of content coming dynamically. I have created another webview to get the height of content but it returns wrong height and sometimes text is not shown. So whole view is ruined.I need to show html content without scrolling. I tried RichtextBlock but it does not parse all html tags properly. Can somebody provide a solution to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching a lot All I could find was an alternative. It's not perfect but works ok. We can decode the string as html and use built in functionality to get string out of html text. It supports very less tags and most tag functionality like Bold and other tags are not visible yet better than removing all tags from code. Hope it helps someone else looking for answer.